# In Excel, comparing a cell with text to see if it is contained in any cells of another column of text.

Tags: excel

I have one column that has the first and last name of subscribers and a second column that just has the last name of the subscribers.  I need to see if the last name in the second column is contained in any of the names in column 1.  Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Array formula: `=MATCH(B1,RIGHT($A$1:$A$2,LEN($A$1:$A$2)-FIND(" ",$A$1:$A$2)),0)`.

Answer (score 2):

If the list of full names is in column `A` (in a `firstname surname` format) and the name you're checking is in cell `B1`, then you can use the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"* "&B1)
```